# decluttering UI, order Extension gets applied

Tags: silverstripe

A few years ago I made a SilverStripe website and added too many fields to Page.php. I'm reworking some of this at the moment but cannot afford do reinvent the Project - now on SilverStripe 3.1.10.

I thought to declutter the UI for Page Sub-Classes, that do not need all the inherited fields, with a few Extensions.

An example how this extension could look

```
class NoClutter extends Extension {
    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
        $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Main", "MenuTitle");
        $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Main", "Workflow");
    }
}
```

config.yml

```
RedirectorPage:
  extensions:
    - NoClutter
```

This works on all classes for fields added in `SiteTree` (such as the *MenuTitle* field), but not for fields added in `Page` (such as the *Workflow* field). If the Extension is on `UserDefinedForm`, *Workflow* is also removed. But it does not work if the extension is on `RedirectorPage`. *MenuTitle* on the other hand is removed in both classes. My guess it's about order. My project is `After: 'framework/','cms/'` and hope I can make an extension like `NoClutter` work within the project.

How can I achieve this or how else could I work around the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `$this->extend('updateCMSFields', $fields)` at the end of your `Page` `getCMSFields()` function.

```php
class Page extends SiteTree {

    // ...

    public function getCMSFields() {
        // call updateCMSFields after adding your fields
        SiteTree::disableCMSFieldsExtensions();
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        SiteTree::enableCMSFieldsExtensions();

        // ...

        $this->extend('updateCMSFields', $fields);

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

`$this->extend('updateCMSFields', $fields)` declares where your code `updateCMSFields()` function will get called.

The problem you are having is `updateCMSFields()` is getting called before you add your custom fields in the `Page` `getCMSFields()` function. So you are trying to remove the *Workflow* field before it is added. This is because the updateCMSFields extension hook is declared in the parent `SiteTree` `getCMSFields()` function.

`UserDefinedForm` solves this by calling `$this->extend('updateCMSFields', $fields)` at the bottom of its `getCMSFields()`. `SiteTree::disableCMSFieldsExtensions()` is required before `parent::getCMSFields()` is called for the extension hook to work.

Comment: urgh to myself - thank you 3dgoo and stackoverflow :)